# Cannot save script without scrapy shutting down

Tags: python, scrapy, fastapi

I am running my scrapy script that combines both `FastAPI` with `Scrapy`, and the integration works successfully. However, when I attempt to save any changes made to the script then `scrapy` begins shutting doing, suggesting that scrapy has not closed whilst I am running on the localhost.

For example:
My router script --

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from collections import defaultdict
from spiders.xp import postItem
import sys

rout = APIRouter()

#global variable
globalDict = defaultdict(list)

@rout.post("/event")
async def add_todo(tealium: dict = None):
    if tealium is not None:
    #locally grab from the post request and store globally
        print(tealium)
        
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
                "FEEDS": {
                    "post.json": {"format": "json"},
                },
            })
        process.crawl(postItem, tealium=tealium)
        
        process.start(stop_after_crawl=True)

        if "twisted.internet.reactor" in sys.modules:
            del sys.modules["twisted.internet.reactor"]
      
        with open('post.json', 'r') as f:
            value = f.read()
        globalDict['value'].append([value])
        print(globalDict)

        return {'message': 'Post request completed'}

    else:
        print(tealium)
        globalDict['result'] = ['No Post Request Sent']
        return globalDict

@rout.get("/event")
async def retrieve_todos() -> dict:
    return { "todos": globalDict}
```

My app script --

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from router.router1 import rout

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def welcome() -> dict:
    return { "message": 'Hello World!' }

app.include_router(rout)
```

I can send `POST` requests and `GET` requests but I cannot make changes whilst the host is running. How can I make sure scrapy does not shutdown after making a save?

Comment: Keeping code running while swapping out the code beneath it is a hard problem to do - especially for a long running process in this case. Instead, move the scrapy code out to its own application (instead of running in the FastAPI process) and for example use a database (like sqlite) for exchanging information between your FastAPI application and your scrapy application).

Comment: @MatsLindh That is definitely an option; It works successfully as long as I do not have to make adjustments to the script. However, it may be more appropriate to attempt your method as mentioned.

Comment: If you need to make updates to that script regularly, you should instead keep track of state in a way that you can restore it - i.e. how long in your scraping session did you come? What URLs are still in the queue? i.e. - that way you'll also handle servers and processes dying for other reasons, instead of just being reloaded because of code changes.